# react-player not playing <video> tag from html

Tags: html, reactjs, go, video

I have create a static web page with golang

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "net/http"
  "html/template"
)

func ex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("static/example.html")
    t.Execute(w, nil)
}

func main() {
  fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
  http.Handle("/", fs)
  imagesHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./video/"))
  http.Handle("/video/", http.StripPrefix("/video/", imagesHandler))
    http.HandleFunc("/ex", ex)

  log.Println("Listening...")
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

example.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="/video/87.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

So if I go to localhost:8080/ex on my browser I can see the video playing and everything

in my react app I am doing the following (I am using import ReactPlayer from 'react-player')

```
render() {
        return (
            <ReactPlayer url='http://localhost:8080/ex' playing controls height='400'/>
        )
    }
```

The video is not working - if I change the url with a youtube video it is working fine. Could you assist me on that

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are passing a HTML page to `url` parameter and not a video URL. Shouldn't you pass `url='/video/87.mp4'` ?

Comment: thanks for that so what I did and now its working fine is the following:

changed             <ReactPlayer url='http://localhost:8080/ex' playing controls height='400'/>


to 

            <ReactPlayer url='http://localhost:8080/video/87.mp4' playing controls height='400'/>